# Custom UITableViewCell background goes transparent after selection

Tags: iphone, uitableview

When selecting, and holding, one of my custom cells for a `UITableView` plain-style table, it displays my custom selection color (`redColor` in this case), but then if I keep it held down and scroll, the custom selection color *and* the custom background disappear (showing through to the `UIImageView` behind the table.

The `UITableView` is created in IB and has a background set to `clearColor` to allow an image to show through.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle 
                         reuseIdentifier:kCellIdentifier] 
                autorelease];

        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;

        /* Background */
        cell.backgroundView = [[[UIImageView alloc] init] autorelease];
        cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[[UIImageView alloc] init] autorelease];
    }

    cell.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"customBackground"]];
    cell.selectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    return cell;
}
```

Can anyone help?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I solved this.  Basically you cannot use `initWithPatternImage` when customizing a `UITableViewCell`.  After it is selected, it's background view must either go transparent, or be removed from the view hierarchy.

Use the following:

```
((UIImageView*)cell.backgroundView).image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"customBackground"];
((UIImageView*)cell.selectedBackgroundView).image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"selectedBackground"];
```